# Wp_query...a type of term a different div

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query, terms

[image]

I need to create a table like this image and I want a specific term in particular DIV but with my code appear all together.

**Example**: One div brown with the 5 products.

The effect I want is like an accordion "Hide and Show".
So if I do not have all the same hide and show the query does not work.
The end result has to be like this image on a div for each term.
At this point I have a div with all terms.

how I can create a div and each has your term?

Thanks for helping.

```
<?php
        $args = array (
                'post_type'=> 'coleccoes',
                'tax_query' => array(
                                                array(
                                                    'taxonomy' => 'tag-series',
                                                    'field' => 'slug', 
                                                    'terms' => array('casegoods','rugs','lighting','seating')))); ?>

<div id="coleccao_casegood">

<?php      $list_query = new WP_Query($args); 
       while ($list_query->have_posts()) : $list_query->the_post();


       if( has_term( 'rugs', 'tag-series' ) ) {
            echo '<h3 class="imagem">';
            the_post_thumbnail();
            echo '</h3>';
            echo '<div class="conteudo" style="top: 650px; position: absolute;">';
            the_content();
            echo '</div>';
} elseif ( has_term( 'seating', 'tag-series' ) ) {
            echo '<h3 class="imagem">';
            the_post_thumbnail();
            echo '</h3>';
            echo '<div class="conteudo" style="top: 650px; position: absolute;">';
            the_content();
            echo '</div>';
} elseif ( has_term( 'lighting', 'tag-series' ) ) {
            echo '<h3 class="imagem">';
            the_post_thumbnail();
            echo '</h3>';
            echo '<div class="conteudo" style="top: 650px; position: absolute;">';
            the_content();
            echo '</div>';
} elseif ( has_term( 'casegoods', 'tag-series' ) ) {
            echo '<h3 class="imagem">';
            the_post_thumbnail();
            echo '</h3>';
            echo '<div class="conteudo" style="top: 650px; position: absolute;">';
            the_content();
            echo '</div>';
} 

    endwhile; 
        wp_reset_query();
        ?> 
 </div> 
<!-- fim div_collection -->
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.conteudo').hide(); 
  $('h3.imagem').click(function() {
    $(this).next('div').slideToggle('fast')
    .siblings('div:visible').slideUp('fast');
  }); 
});
</script>
```

**It is thus**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to just create [conditional statements](http://www.php.net//manual/en/control-structures.if.php) checking for the term and wrapping it in a div of your choice.

After you loop starts you could do something like:

```
while ($list_query->have_posts()) : $list_query->the_post();

if( has_term( 'casegoods', 'tag-series' ) ) {
    echo '<div class="left-side">';
    the_content();
    echo '</div>';
} elseif ( has_term( 'casegoods', 'rugs' ) ) {
   // do something else
} //..etc
```

Comment: I apreciate your post is very help full but i have the same problem because is not as it is in the picture.
I'll put the image as is.

Comment: This is a CSS problem and not really related to WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible (and fairly common) to run multiple loops in the same template, pulling different groups of content for different areas, just use the WP function `wp_reset_postdata();` after each.   Your `<div> </div>` tag pair will contain each query and results.

I believe you are looking for this type of structure:

```
<div id="casegoods">
<?php 
  $args = .....;
  $case_query = new WP_Query( $args );
  .... loop and do stuff ....
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_query(): ?>
</div>

<div id="seating">
<?php 
  $args = .....;
  $seating_query = new WP_Query( $args );
  .... loop and do stuff ....
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_query(): ?>
</div>
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer but i need create only one wp_query because my script if do not have it all together does not work.

<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.demo-show2> div').hide(); 
  $('div.demo-show2> h3').click(function() {
    $(this).next('div').slideToggle('fast')
    .siblings('div:visible').slideUp('fast');
  }); 
});
</script>

Comment: What is the failure?

Comment: Your JS is targeting the demo-show2 class.  Seems easier to modify the JS than ask WP to do something to fit the script. It would have saved a good deal of time if the JS were part of your question.

Comment: It's very difficult to read code in comments, since it all get spit out on a single line. Please [edit your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/150287/edit) with your JavaScript code, to provide us with a better idea what you want us to answer.

Comment: I edited the article